# Logback XML to YML (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback, slf4j, spring-logback

I have the following Logback/SLF4J XML configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="m"
                    converterClass="com.mycompany.logging.MyCustomConverter" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="message"
                    converterClass="com.mycompany.logging.MyCustomConverter" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="msg"
                    converterClass="com.mycompany.logging.MyCustomConverter" />
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            </layout>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Is there an equivalent Spring Boot YML configuration?

Specifically wondering about the `conversionRule` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent some time looking for this myself -- the YML configurations stay at the generic facade level, whereas the conversionRule would be specific to logback.

Ended up just leaving the xml configuration with no `level` set on the appender, controlling the level via the YML, or in my case dynamically being set as needed.